# Android Studio (Windows 7) does not detect ASUS Zenfone. Cannot run my app

Tags: usb-debugging, android-sdk

So, I will list the problems one by one. Please help.

1. I plug phone into laptop's USB using Phone's own data/ charger cable. Everything is ok. Phone is in `MTP` mode.
2. Android Studio does not detect the phone when I try to run my app.
3. Device Manager shows an `exclamation mark` on ADB Interface, but my ASUS is connected as a portable device. (I downloaded the exact drivers for the phone, however, manually trying to select those driver to update the ADB interface fails)
4. ADB Wireless (No Root) is installed on phone, but my computer fails to do a detection with the adb commands: `devices`, `tcpip 5555`, and `usb`, giving the message `Error: device not found`.
5. As some solutions suggested, switching to `PTP` mode does not help either.
6. The ASUS phone always wants to install a Share Link software when it's connected. Is this what is blocking a simple USB data connection?

**Question:** What might be the problem, and the workaround?

Comment: as per asus site https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1007320 you should use asus PC link for debugging. As a general rule 'USB Debugging" should be enabled for ADB to work. Try using latest adb installed away from your sdk.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on the USB debugging for ADB to work.
To turn on USB debugging:
Navigate to Settings > About Phone > scroll to the bottom > tap Build number seven 7 times. You'll get toast saying that you're now a developer. 2. Go back and now you can see  the Developer options in settings, check 'USB debugging' and click OK.
Some times you may need to install drivers for your phone. You can download it from manufactures website.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when the phone driver does not install try using http://pdanet.co/a/ Install the app when the phone is connected to the laptop. Even if the installation fails for some reason you still might get the driver for the phone ins